# Use Alex macros from another file

Tags: haskell, macros, alex

Is there any way to have an Alex macro defined in one source file and used in other source files? In my case, I have definitions for `$LowerCaseLetter` and `$UpperCaseLetter` (these are all letters except `e` and `O`, since they have special roles in my code). How can I refer to these macros from other `.x` files?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework, Flex?

Comment: @Reboog711 I didn't. I should have read the description before adding the tag.

Comment: The tag `Flex-Lexer` is used for the lexical analyzer; and that is commonly mis-tagged as just `flex`.  However I don't know enough about it to know whether that is an appropriate tag for your question.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Disproving something exists is always harder than finding something that does exist, but I think the info below does show that Alex can only get macro definitions from the .x file it is reading (other than predefinied stuff like `$white`), and not via includes from other files....

You can get the sourcecode for Alex by doing the following:

```
> cabal unpack alex
> cd alex-3.1.3
```

In src/Main.hs, predefined macros are first set in variables called `initSetEnv` (charset macros `$white`, `$printable`, and "."), and `initREEnv` (regexp macros, there are none).  This gets passed into runP, in src/ParseMonad.hs, which is used to hold the current parsing state, including all defined macros.  The initial state is set using the values passed in, but macros can be added using a function called `newSMac` (or `newRMac` for regular expression macros).

Since this seems to be the only way that macros can be set, it is then only a matter of some grep bookkeeping to verify the only ways that macros can be added is through an actual macro definition in the source .x file.  Unsurprisingly, Alex recursively uses its own .x/.y files for .x source file parsing (src/parser.y, src/Scan.x).  It is a couple of levels of indirection away, but you can verify that the only way `newSMac` can be called is through the src/Scan.x macro

```
@smac   = \$ @id | \$ \{ @id \}
<0> @smac @ws? \=       { smacdef }
```

---

Other than some obvious predefined stuff, I don't believe reuse in lexers is all that typical anyway, because at the token level things are usually pretty simple (often simple tokens like `SPACE`, `WORD`, `NUMBER`, and a few operators, symbols and parens are all that are needed).  The complexity comes at the parsing stage, although for technical reasons, parser-includes aren't that common either (see scannerless parsing for a newer technology that does allow reuse through nesting, like javascript embedded in html....  The tools for scannerless parsing are still pretty primitive though).